# Do not allow users to edit database from query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I made a page where the users can put in a query in a textarea, and when they click the submit button it generates a table filled with data from that query.

Now i want to make sure that the users can not use other kind of query's like: INSERT , DROP , ALTER , UPDATE , RENAME and all the others that can edit tables in the database.

I could not find any good examples. (or did not search correct)

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered searching for the words "insert"/"drop"/"alter" etc, and if found, then just giving an error message?

Comment: You can set the desired permissions for a new MySQL user and connect to the database with that user. Can't be bypassed so it's quite safe.

Comment: You could have created a form with options and when the form would be submitted, it would create the query and execute it. No more worries.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new user for this purpose. This user should only have [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_select) access to the database.

```
GRANT SELECT ON database_name.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

Utilizing this method, you don't have to mess with regex's (unless you want client side validation) and even if your validation fails, the database itself will handle the permissions appropriately.

Your form needs to use `someuser` to connect and run the query, not the user that the rest of your application uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GRANT` if using MySQL and restrict dbuser for DMLs. i dont know the exact Syntax for that. Or you can also validate the Query by `regex` or `stripos`